# python parse conditional xml value

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

Here is my XML file:

```
<METAR>
<wind_dir_degrees>210</wind_dir_degrees>
<wind_speed_kt>14</wind_speed_kt>
<wind_gust_kt>22</wind_gust_kt>
</METAR>
```

Here is my script to parse the wind direction and speed. However, the wind gust is a conditional value and doesn't always appear in my xml file. I'd like to show the value if it does exist and nothing if it doesn't.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib import urlopen

link = urlopen('xml file')

tree = ET.parse(link)
root = tree.getroot()

data = root.findall('data/METAR')
for metar in data:
    print metar.find('wind_dir').text
```

I tried something like this but get errors

```
data = root.findall('wind_gust_kt')
for metar in data:
        if metar.find((wind_gust_kt') > 0:
           print "Wind Gust: ", metar.find('wind_gust_kt').text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findtext` with a default value of `''`, eg:

```
print "Wind Gust: ", meta.findtext('wind_gust_kt', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over the result of the `findall` function, there is no need to
call `find` again--you already have the element.

You can simplify your code to something like this:

```
tree = ET.parse(link)
for wind_gust in tree.findall('wind_gust_kt'):
    print "Wind gust:", wind_gust.text
```

You might have been following this tutorial:

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial

In the example there, the `find` method of the loop variable is called
in order to find child elements of the loop element.  In your case,
the `wind_gust` variable is the element that you want, and it has no child elements.